# cell text for two dynamically sections

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, tableview

I have two `tableView` sections, sometimes the first section dosen't have any data in it so the second one now comes the first.

In my `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method I'm counting my first array:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if (appDelegate.firstArray.count == 0) {
    numberOfSections = 1;
} else {
    numberOfSections = 2;
}
return self.numberOfSections;
```

**`numberOfSections`** its an **int** into my header file.

and here's how I configure my text for cells

```
switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
    {
        MyClass *inFirstArray = [appDelegate.firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = inFirstArray.title;
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        Event *inSecondArray = [appDelegate.secondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = inSecondArray.title;
        break;    

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

The problem is that if my firstArray count equals to 0, I don't have any text into my secondArray...

**UPDATE**

Also have this methods

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    //I'm realeasing it into dealloc
    sectionTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [sectionTitles addObject:@"first ArrayTitle"];
    [sectionTitles addObject:@"second ArrayTitle"];
    NSString *sectionText = [sectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    return sectionText;
}
```

and

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //Adding a custom background image for table section header
    NSString *title = [times objectAtIndex:section];
    UIView *customView = [ [ [UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, -5.0, 320.0, 25.0) ] autorelease ];
    [customView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableBackground.png"]]];
    UIButton *button = [ [ [ UIButton alloc ] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(-9.0, 5.0, 320, 27.0) ] autorelease ];
    button.tag = section;
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header_section_background.png" ] forState: UIControlStateNormal ];
    button.highlighted = NO;
    button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    UILabel *label = [ [ UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15.0, 5.0, 45, 22.0) ];
    label.alpha = 1.0;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    label.text = title;
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;

    [customView addSubview: button ];
    [customView addSubview:label ];
    [customView sendSubviewToBack:button];

    return customView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always return 2 for your `numberOfSections`. For your `numberOfRowsInSection`, do the following:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    
    if (section == 0)
        return [appDelegate.firstArray count];
    else
        return [appDelegate.secondArray count];
}
```

So your two sections will always exist, but will have zero rows if there is no data for them.